# Add a sidekiq monitor page into rails admin

Tags: ruby, rails-admin, sidekiq-monitor

How to add a sidekiq monitor page into rails admin?

I have tried to use custom action but I don't know how to use mount method in rails admin.

Does this have a good solution?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring

Comment: What, specifically, isn't clear from the documentation on that page?

Comment: It said how to add sidekiq page into my app. But I want to show it in /admin/sidekiq

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to have `sidekiq_monitor` gem in your `Gemfile`.

Like this:

```
sidekiq (3.5.1)
sidekiq-failures (0.4.5)
sidekiq-lock (0.3.0)
sidekiq_monitor (0.1.7)
rails_admin (0.7.0)
```

Offourse follow setup of `sidekiq_monitor`, and you will find link to 'Jobs' on left menu panel in rails admin.

And your links will looks like: `/admin/sidekiq~monitor~job`

[image]